# Touch events not binding as described in documentation Foundation 6.5.3

Tags: javascript, zurb-foundation

I have been trying to setup basic touch events per the [documentation](https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/javascript-utilities.html) for Foundation 6.5.3 javascript utilities. What they provide as sample code simply doesn't work. I get a type error for the addTouch method and the 'swipeleft' event is not properly bound either.

I have setup a [codepen](https://codepen.io/joedy-felts/pen/JjjZEqY?editors=1111) to demonstrate this.

```
<div class="grid-container">
    <div class="grid-x grid-padding-x">
        <div id="test" class="small-12 medium-6 cell">
            <p>Touch test.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
function handleLeftSwipe(){
  console.log('Successful swipe left.');
}

function handleDrag(){
  console.log('Successful handle drag.');
}

$('#test').addTouch().on('mousemove', handleDrag);
// Binds elements to touch events. Used in the Slider plugin for mobile devices.

$('#test').on('swipeleft', handleLeftSwipe);
// Binds elements to swipe events. Used in the Orbit plugin for mobile devices.
</script>
```

When I run this simple demo locally I get `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).addTouch is not a function` as an error. No swipe or touch events are bound to the element I am assigning them to per the javascript.

Comment: Just to be sure, are you properly loading `js/foundation.util.touch.js`? Looks like it's needed for this functionality

Comment: @Andrew Yes. In our production build, where we are compiling our own app.bundle.js file foundation.util.touch.js is being imported. I can confirm it is working with orbit components in our build.


In the codepen I setup I believe it is built into the foundation javascript for 6.5.3. I have it successfully consoling out Touch in the console.


Is it possible the documentation is just woefully out of date with the feature set of 6.5.3? Is anyone setting up their own touch or swipe events using Foundation that could help?

Comment: Honestly, I couldn't get it working either, but I am very unfamiliar with Foundation. Maybe the docs *are* out of date. Perhaps you could contribute to them if you found a solution?

Comment: The code is (still) there, see https://github.com/foundation/foundation-sites/blob/develop/js/foundation.util.touch.js#L122. Does the same happen with the unminified version?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Yes, this code is present in our unminified app.bundle.js.